# django social auth limiting user data

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I have configured [django social auth's](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to take from google only e-mail, but google shows this screen alerting app user that gender, date of birth, picture, language will be collect:

[image]

My django-social-auth config is as follow:

```
WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS = [ 'some_domain', ]
GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS = WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS
SOCIAL_AUTH_EXTRA_DATA = False    
#LOGIN_ERROR_URL    = '/login-error/' Not set
#SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user' Not set
#GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY          = '' Not set
#GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET       = '' Not set
#GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID      = '' Not set
#GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET  = '' Not set
SOCIAL_AUTH_USERNAME_IS_FULL_EMAIL = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS = ['email',]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
     ...
    'social_auth',
)
```

**How can I do to avoid this google message?**

**EDITED**

I have move to GoogleOauth2 auth and inherit and change google backend:

```
from social_auth.backends.google import *

GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',]

class GoogleOAuth2(BaseOAuth2):
    """Google OAuth2 support"""
    AUTH_BACKEND = GoogleOAuth2Backend
    AUTHORIZATION_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
    ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
    REVOKE_TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke'
    REVOKE_TOKEN_METHOD = 'GET'
    SETTINGS_SECRET_NAME = 'GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET'
    SCOPE_VAR_NAME = 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_EXTRA_SCOPE'
    DEFAULT_SCOPE = GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE
    REDIRECT_STATE = False

    print DEFAULT_SCOPE  #<------ to be sure

    def user_data(self, access_token, *args, **kwargs):
        """Return user data from Google API"""
        return googleapis_profile(GOOGLEAPIS_PROFILE, access_token)

    @classmethod
    def revoke_token_params(cls, token, uid):
        return {'token': token}

    @classmethod
    def revoke_token_headers(cls, token, uid):
        return {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
```

But google still ask for profile data, profile is still in scope:

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&redirect_uri=...

Runs fine if I modify by hand social-auth code instead inherit:

```
def get_scope(self):
    return ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',]
```

**What is wrong with my code?**

Comment: Have you defined the new backend in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`?

Comment: Yes, and `print DEFAULT_SCOPE` outpùt is the new scope but ... I have another print into your django-auth code and that print outputs includes userinfo.profile.

Comment: What happens if you override `get_scope()` on the new class? Also remove the other backend from that same setting.

Comment: Also tried unsuccessfully. But from now, this is a development issue. Thanks to you to point to exact social auth module to overwrite. I check your answer as solution and I will test for final approach, middle time, if you found a solution, please, post it. Thanks about your job and to share this valuables piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the default scope used on google backend is set to that (email and profile information), it's defined [here](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/abb511f63a29b8e2399e15f45114bab27110985f/social_auth/backends/google.py#L48). In order to avoid that you can create your own google backend which just sets the desired scope, then use that backend instead of the built in one. Example:

```
from social_auth.backends.google import GoogleOAuth2

class SimplerGoogleOAuth2(GoogleOAuth2):
    DEFAULT_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']
```

Answer (score 1):

Those who don't know how to add in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, if using the way Omab suggested you need to add newly defined backend in your setting.py file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'app_name.file_name.class_name',  #ex: google_auth.views.SimplerGoogleOAuth2
    # 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2', # comment this as no longer used
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

To know how to create the **class SimplerGoogleOAuth2** check Omab's answer.